# Truncating multi-indexed dataframe

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I am pulling in data from several air-quality monitoring stations.  Each station should record the same parameters (e.g. O3, NO2, SO2, etc.).  I could put everything into one dataframe by adding more columns, but this becomes sloppy.

It makes sense to put the data into a multi-indexed dataframe; however, I would like to selectively extract the data (e.g. pull out data from station "A", then truncate within specified date range, then calculate stats).  However, I am having difficulty figuring out how to trunctate a multi-indexed dataframe and begin to believe it is not possible.  Posted below is an example dataframe to give an idea of what I am dealing with.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dates = pd.date_range('20130101',periods=3,freq='5s')
dates = dates.append(dates)

locations = list('AAABBB')
gascode = ['no2','o3','so2']*2

tup = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples( zip(locations,gascode,dates), names=['Location','gas','Date'] )

data = pd.DataFrame(data=range(6),index=tup,columns=['val1'])

>>> data

Location gas Date                  val1         
A        no2 2013-01-01 00:00:00     0
         o3  2013-01-01 00:00:05     1
         so2 2013-01-01 00:00:10     2
B        no2 2013-01-01 00:00:00     3
         o3  2013-01-01 00:00:05     4
         so2 2013-01-01 00:00:10     5
```

Normally I would make date the master (and sole) index, but this is not feasible since the date stamps will not be unique (i.e. there will be a 2013-01-01 00:00:00 marker for O3, NO2, SO2, etc. for EACH location).

Is it possible to truncate via a tertiary index?
I have considered converting the data to a pivot table, but I do not believe that is the best route to go.  In this case multi-indexing makes the most sense IF I can sort out the date issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multi-index has an implicit concept of hierarchy; if your computations tend to break this hierarchy then you may be better off not to use mult-index. As for your example, you may achieve what you want to do with a different order for the indices. That is if the dataframe was indexed by `['Location','Date','gas']` ( in that order )

```
                                  val1
Location Date                gas      
A        2013-01-01 00:00:00 no2     0
         2013-01-01 00:00:05 o3      1
         2013-01-01 00:00:10 so2     2
B        2013-01-01 00:00:00 no2     3
         2013-01-01 00:00:05 o3      4
         2013-01-01 00:00:10 so2     5
```

you could use `ix` as in:

```
df.ix[ 'A' ].ix[ pd.Timestamp( '2013-01-01 00:00:05' ):pd.Timestamp( '2013-01-01 00:00:10' )]
```

which outputs:

```
                         val1
Date                gas      
2013-01-01 00:00:05 o3      1
2013-01-01 00:00:10 so2     2
```

or for a single column:

```
df.val1[ 'A' ][ pd.Timestamp( '2013-01-01 00:00:05' ):pd.Timestamp( '2013-01-01 00:00:10' )]
```

which outputs:

```
Date                 gas
2013-01-01 00:00:05  o3     1
2013-01-01 00:00:10  so2    2
Name: val1, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Actually, this works quite well without rearranging the indices by going one layer deeper:
    df.ix['locID'].ix['gasID'].ix[time1:tim2]

Thanks for the help!

Comment: @tnknepp right, but in your example you were not filtering for the "gas" type

Comment: My fault, I did not intend to leave out that tid-bit.  Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest/Fastest is probably to select out the dates you need before aggregation.

```
In [19]: data
Out[19]: 
                                  val1
Location gas Date                     
A        no2 2013-01-01 00:00:00     0
         o3  2013-01-01 00:00:05     1
         so2 2013-01-01 00:00:10     2
B        no2 2013-01-01 00:00:00     3
         o3  2013-01-01 00:00:05     4
         so2 2013-01-01 00:00:10     5

[6 rows x 1 columns]

In [20]: x = data.reset_index()

In [21]: x[(x.Date > '20130101 00:00:00') & (x.Date < '20130101 00:00:10')].set_index(data.index.names)
Out[21]: 
                                  val1
Location gas Date                     
A        o3  2013-01-01 00:00:05     1
B        o3  2013-01-01 00:00:05     4

[2 rows x 1 columns]
```